# How to turn this array composed of arrays into an array composed of objects (defining new properties)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to turn this: `[[a1, b1], [a2, b2]]` into this? `[{x1: a1, y2: b1}, {x2: a2, y2: b2}]`?

Note: the `x1` and `x2` are newly defined properties (with `a1`, `b1`, etc. as values).

Note: This is what I tried:

```
formatData.map((data, index) => {
  const obj = {
    dataX: data[index][0],
    dataY: data[index][2]
  }
  data = obj
}
```

But became stuck.

Comment: look up the .map() method of array

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not show any sign of effort. This is a requirement and not a problem statement.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: please add a valid result with given data.

Comment: Just a pointer, using a map where you do not respect its output or do not return anything from callback is a BAD implementation.

Comment: what if you have array like `[['a1', 'b1','c1'], ['a2', b2'],['a3']]` ?

Comment: @alex : DId my answer worked for you ?

Comment: Why is it x1 and y2, then x2 and y2? Why isn't is x1 and y1? Why do the keys in each object need to be different? Can't you just call them x and y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the values and take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for new objects.

```js
var keys = ['x', 'y'],
    data = [['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2']],
    result = data.map(a => Object.assign(...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));
    
console.log(result);
```

With an object for the wanted keys and corresponding indices.

```js
var keys = { x: 0, y: 2 },
    data = [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']],
    result = data.map(a => Object.assign(...Object
        .keys(keys)
        .map(k => ({ [k]: a[keys[k]] }))
    ));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please let OP to share effort. Answering such question promotes spoon feeding

Comment: @Rajesh, not here `[{x1: a1, y2: b1} ...`.

Comment: @Rajesh, once the answer meets and satisfies the desired output I think that't not a problem. Also, OP includes what he tried in answer :)

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai OP just added code. And the point is, since we are older users, we should try to enforce and maintain certain discipline. This still is my POV, but I guess we should not promote spoon feeding

Comment: @Rajesh, my pov is, if there is already an answe, but it could be better, then i make my answer for it. but i think this q is a dupe.

Comment: *but it could be better, then i make my answer*, I know this and I respect you a lot for this. But still in my POV, we should wait to see what OP has tried so far. That enables us to answer in a way OP just does not solves current problem but also learn something in the process.

Comment: What if I have 3 values? And I don't want the middle one in the result?

`var data = [[‘a1’, ‘b1’, ‘c1’], [‘a2’, ‘b2’, ‘c2’]] // =>  x1: a1, y1: c1  no b1 value`

Comment: @alex, then you could take an object with the keys instead of an array for getting the wanted parts.

Comment: @alex, if you'd spent more time on your question you could have included that query there.

Answer (score 3):

Simple for loop can do this

```js
var arr = [["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"]];
var newArr = [];
var repeater = ['x','y','z'];//...
for(var i in arr){
  var obj = {};
  for(var j in arr[i]){  
    obj[repeater[j]+(parseInt(i)+1)] = arr[i][j];
  }
  newArr.push(obj);
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Please do not answer such question. Let OP share effort. Don't promote spoon feeding

Comment: @Rajesh : I was only able to anwer. I Didn't comment to say anything, because of lower reputation, but next time I will do this. Thanks

Comment: The expectation is key with x1 & y1 and so no , but in your case the keys are x0,x1...

Comment: @brk : I have updated my answer : Please share you comment if you feel its good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` of array as below

```
var temp = [['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2']];

temp.map(function(arr,index){
   var ret = {};
   ret['x'+(index+1)]= arr[0];
   ret['y'+(index+1)]= arr[1];
   return ret;
});

//"[{"x1":"a1","y1":"b1"},{"x2":"a2","y2":"b2"}]"
```

Comment: Please let OP to share effort. Answering such question promotes spoon feeding

Comment: Agreed we should not do spoon feeding,

I guess OP added efforts now.

Comment: Yes he did now. But the point is, should we not wait to see if OP has tried something and then provide solution? In my POV, SO is to solve problem statements and not requirements.

Comment: Yep, will take care of that next time.

Comment: What if I have 3 values? And I don't want the middle one in the result?

`var data = [[‘a1’, ‘b1’, ‘c1’], [‘a2’, ‘b2’, ‘c2’]] // =>  x1: a1, y1: c1  no b1 value`

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach`

```js
var m = [
  ['a1', 'b1'],
  ['a2', 'b2']
];
var tempArray = []
m.forEach(function(item, index) {
  // create a local object to set the key and value into it
  var localObj = {};
  // setting key and value
  localObj['x' + 1] = item[0];
  localObj['y' + 1] = item[1]
  // push that pbject to an array
  tempArray.push(localObj)
})

console.log(tempArray)
```

Comment: What if I have 3 values? And I don't want the middle one in the result?

`var data = [[‘a1’, ‘b1’, ‘c1’], [‘a2’, ‘b2’, ‘c2’]] // =>  x1: a1, y1: c1  no b1 value`

Comment: in that case you need to maintain an array of keys like `[a,b,c,d]`